# Can't get a list of people whose birthday in current month

Tags: civireport, advanced-search

We want to see a list of people who have birthday next month. Advanced search doesn't suit us because it is trying to do search only for a current year. We use SYSTOPIA Birthdays for generating upcoming birthday report (this month). Then we configured scheduled job to send this monthly mail report. But somehow date when report sent is moving forward: one month it was sent at the first day of month, the other month at the second day etc. We need to send this report at the very first day of the month. If it sends a mail report at for example seventh day then we don't see people whose birthday was in the first days of the month. Is there any way to solve this problem?

CiviCRM version - 5.10.2

Comment: What CMS are you? 

We've done something similar, but ended up using Drupal views to get the data  exported to CSV

Comment: We are using WordPress

Comment: Is the problem that you can't get a list of birthdays, or that the date of the scheduled job keeps mysteriously changing? I think the post title might be misleading some people and this is really a scheduled job question.

Answer (score 1):

This extension should help with your requirement –

https://civicrm.org/extensions/birthdays-month

[image]